# image size changed after uploading with loopj AsyncHttpClient in Android

Tags: android

I'm uploading image from my Android application to my server.

In the phone my image size is 1.5MB after uploading the size of the image is 250KB

Image width and height didn't change

```
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    File myFile = new File(imagePath);
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    try {
        params.put("img", myFile);
        params.put("key1", request.getText().toString());
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("MyApp", "File not found!!!" + imagePath);
    }
    client.post(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            answer.setText(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String arg1) {
        super.onFailure(arg0, arg1);
        Log.d("MyApp", arg0.getMessage().toString());
        }

    });
```

in the server, i'm getting the image with the below servlet code:

```
    Part part = request.getPart("key1");
    Part img = request.getPart("img");
    if (part!=null && img!=null){
        String name = getValue(part);
        InputStream is = img.getInputStream();
        BufferedImage bufImage = ImageIO.read(is); 
        ImageIO.write(bufImage, "jpg", new File("c:/file_"+name+".jpg"));
        out.println(name + " I got your image ");
    } else {
        out.println("image upload failed");
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the problem was in the servlet, below is the solution

```
Part fName = request.getPart("name");
Part img = request.getPart("img");
if (fName!=null && img!=null){
    String name = getValue(fName);
    InputStream is = img.getInputStream();
    OutputStream o = new FileOutputStream("c:/file_"+name+".jpg"); 
    copy(is, o); //The function is below 
    o.flush(); 
    o.close(); 
    out.println(name + " I got your image ");
} else {
    out.println("image upload failed");
}
out.flush();
out.close();

public static long copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException { 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; 

    long count = 0L; 
    int n = 0; 

    while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) { 
        output.write(buffer, 0, n); 
        count += n; 
    } 
    return count; 
}
```